# Procmail - execute Java file

Tags: java, procmail

How can I execute .jar file via procmail?

My recipe:

```
:0
* ^Subject.*test
* B ?? test
| /usr/local/bin/java /home/username/.procmail/printer.jar
```

In present form it doesn't work but if I change executing jar file to forward mail like that:

```
! mail@mail.com
```

It works perfectly.

What to do?

**EDIT**
I just looked into log file and here it is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class .home.Main..procmail.printer.jar
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the argument to Java needs to be a class name, not the path to the file which contains the class definition.

Alternatively, as remarked in a comment, pass the `-jar` option before the jar file name.

Comment: Thank you! Your idea + small name change fixed the issue!